Spring Oauth2 with custom url and signature asymmetric signature
I am very new to Oauth and especially Spring Oauth2. Using basic spring Oauth basic authentication it's a success.
Now I want to custom URL and authentication method:
curl --location 'http://localhost:27113/api/token/b2b
X-TIMESTAMP : DateTime with timezone, which follows the ISO-8601 standard
X-CLIENT-KEY : client_id
X-SIGNATURE : Signature Asymmetric
Content-Type : application/json
{
          "grantType": "client_credentials"
}


=================================

Signature asymmetric :

Generate Signature Asymmetric

SHA256withRSA is used to generate the signature with your Private Key as the key
X-SIGNATURE = SHA256withRSA(PrivateKey, StringToSign) 

Note = X-SIGNATURE should be encoded by Base64

The StringToSign will be a colon-separated list derived from some request data as below :
StringToSign = client_ID+"|"+X-TIMESTAMP 


AuthorizationServiceConfigurerAdapterImpl.java:
public class AuthorizationServiceConfigurerAdapterImpl extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore JdbcTokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
        //.inMemory().withClient("test").accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(
            AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {

        endpoints
                .tokenStore(JdbcTokenStore)
                .pathMapping("/oauth/token"             , "/api/oauth/token")
                .pathMapping("/oauth/authorize"         , "/api/oauth/authorize")
                .pathMapping("/oauth/check_token"      , "/api/oauth/check_token")
                .pathMapping("/oauth/confirm_access"   , "/api/oauth/confirm_access")
                .pathMapping("/oauth/error"               , "/api/oauth/error")
                .pathMapping("/oauth/token"              , "/api/oauth/token")
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        endpoints.addInterceptor((HandlerInterceptor) new SignatureVerificationFilter())
        //endpoints.addInterceptor(new SignatureVerificationInterceptor())
                .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/api/token/b2b");                
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        SignatureVerificationFilter securityFilter = new SignatureVerificationFilter(publicKey());
        registrationBean.setFilter(securityFilter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/token/b2b");
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);
    
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PublicKey publicKey() throws Exception {
        return loadPublicKey();
    }
}

SignatureVerificationFilter.java:
public class SignatureVerificationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private SignatureVerificationService signatureVerificationService;
    private PublicKey publicKey;


    
    public SignatureVerificationFilter(PublicKey publicKey) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
    }

    public SignatureVerificationFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    //@Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader("X-CLIENT-KEY");
    }

    //@Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader("X-SIGNATURE");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String clientId = request.getHeader("X-CLIENT-KEY");
        String timestamp = request.getHeader("X-TIMESTAMP");
        String signature = request.getHeader("X-SIGNATURE");

        try {
            if (!signatureVerificationService.verifySignature(clientId, timestamp, signature)) {
                throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid signature") {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;};
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().write("{\"responseCode\":\"4017300\",\"responseMessage\":\"Unauthorized. [Signature]\"}");
        }
    }
}

SignatureVerificationService.java:
public class SignatureVerificationService {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsRepository clientDetailsRepository;

    public boolean verifySignature(String clientId, String timestamp, String signature) throws JOSEException, ParseException {
        ClientDetails client = clientDetailsRepository.findByClientId(clientId);
        if (client == null) {
            return false;
        }

        String stringToSign = clientId + "|" + timestamp;

        // Base64 decode the signature
        byte[] decodedSignature = Base64.getDecoder().decode(signature);

        // Create JWSObject to represent the JWT
        JWSObject jwsObject = JWSObject.parse(new String(decodedSignature));


        // Parse the public key stored in the database
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) RSAKey.parse(client.getPublicKey()).toPublicKey();

        // Create an RSASSAVerifier with the public key
        RSASSAVerifier verifier = new RSASSAVerifier(publicKey);

        // Verify the signature
        return jwsObject.verify(verifier) && jwsObject.getPayload().toString().equals(stringToSign);
    }
}


All credentials: public key and private key are correct. But it's got the error:

2024-08-12 15:14:54,809 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher [http-nio-27113-exec-6] Checking match of request : '/api/token/b2b'; against '/api/token/b2b'
2024-08-12 15:14:54,810 DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor [http-nio-27113-exec-6] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/token/b2b; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2024-08-12 15:14:54,810 DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor [http-nio-27113-exec-6] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2024-08-12 15:14:54,810 DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased [http-nio-27113-exec-6] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@4866e6fa, returned: -1
2024-08-12 15:14:54,810 DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter [http-nio-27113-exec-6] Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)

